# Scrollmagic + GSAP horizontal scroll for tablets

Tags: javascript, ipad, tablet, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm currently working on a horizontal scrolling website with ScrollMagic and GSAP. It's working well on desktops with mousewheel function. However, when it comes to tablets where mousewheel is not applicable, the anchor navigations don't work and the results when using Chrome and ipad varies (anchor links not working on ipad chrome but works well on ipad safari). I added a drag function for tablets, but it staggers and the animation is not very smooth.

**Mousewheel**

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
    if(e.type != 'wheel'){
        return;
    }
    let delta = ((e.deltaY || -e.wheelDelta || e.detail) >> 1) || 1;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft += delta;
    document.body.scrollLeft += delta;
});
```

Drag

```
const slider = document.querySelector('html');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    slider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if(!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
    //console.log(walk);
});
```

**Codepen example: https://codepen.io/shirasaki/pen/JjEyjgb**

Unfortunately, with recent ipad update, it seems not possible to detect if the user is using an ipad or ipad pro.

Is there something wrong with the code or possibly css that can fix this? Appreciate any help!

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thank you! I'll have a look at this.